# extjs Combobox typeahead / auto selection for single character

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I am using extjs combobox for a sex field. It have two value "M" and "F". I want to make it usable with keyboard:

```
 {
     xtype: 'combo',
     typeAhead: true,
     queryMode: 'local',
     minChars: 1,
     triggerAction: 'all',
     store: [
          ['M', 'M'],
          ['F', 'F']
     ]
 }
```

This works if I type "F<kbd>tab</kbd>" (uppercase), but not "f<kbd>tab</kbd>" (lowercase). If I check the code to this, the typeahead works:

```
 store: [
     ['M', 'Male'],
     ['F', 'Female']
 ]
```

Any ways to keep the value as "M" and have lowercase works?

Comment: Could you confirm the browser and Ext version you're using, I've tested with Ext 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. There is a small bug fixed in 4.0.1 which could be relevant.

Comment: I saw the bug in extjs 4.0.1 on Chrome (lastest dev, 13.something) and IE9.

Comment: I am using this in a editorgrid, just in case it matters. The value reset when I press [tab].

Comment: I've checked with 4.0.2 and there are no issues with Safari, Chrome or Firefox 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if you figured this one out, but I had a similar problem and found the solution:

```
enableKeyEvents : true,
forceSelection : true,
typeAhead : false,
    listeners : 
    {
        'keyup' : function(me)
        {
            var val = me.getRawValue();
            if(val == 'm' || val == 'f')
                me.setValue(val.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
```

I also had a grid that was giving me grief for a simple yes/no type selection in a combobox.  I have searched high and low for an answer, but came up with this hack.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have migrated to jquery. I think it works, but it is not as clean as I wish.

Answer (score 3):

Set the combobox 'caseSensitive' config attribute to false (caseSensitive : false). This should solve problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
listeners: {
  'specialkey': function(field, e) {
    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
      me.searchList(appMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

where appMessage is the message variable passed, and field the value of field to check for special case.